# Do we have an OrderedList for list?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a list variant that automatically keeps the values sorted. Does Python have a thing like OrderedList readily available?

If not, are there recommended alternatives?

Comment: `list` objects are already ordered like `OrderedDict`... *by insertion order*. You want something that maintains *sorted order*, that's entirely different. Python does not provide that, no.... but you probably just want to use the library [`sortedcontainers`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) that provides various drop-in replacements for Python data types that maintain sorted order

Comment: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/